# Issues with cross domain request

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I work on a site that pulls images from multiple CDNs and I want to log which image came from which CDN. These CDNs send an extra header param with the images that names the server that sent the image.

Problems:
- Ajax won't work because of the CORS disabled
- Can't use a proxy or put a proxy file on the CDNs because they only serve images

Any tips how to make this work with JS only?
Or maybe with Flash?

Is there a way to "observe" the network with Javascript (like Firebug or Chrome dev tools) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact solution for your problem but if I were you I would look at websockets.
There are a lot of questions about it there: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=websocket+image+javascript
And I think you should look at this too: http://binaryjs.com/

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to make it work on IE8+, so this solution sadly not available to me (even with the polyfill).